# How to intercept keyboard input at the lowest level in linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, keyboard

I am interested in writing a program for linux that will read ALL keystrokes, process it and THEN output to the rest of the running processes. Essentially, ALL keyboard input must go into this program and this program alone...Then the program will act as the keyboard for the rest of the computer. I basically want to do something like predictive text on android devices, so my program will act as a filter.

What i'm asking is basically how to direct all keyboard events to my program. While i am not looking for code, i would like to know what part of linux programming/ linux system do i have to learn to be able to complete this task? this, because i am doing this in an attempt to better learn linux.

Comment: 1. Obtain the Linux kernel source code. 2. Modify the keyboard driver to do what you want.

Comment: That would mean that I would modify the linux kernel and then have to reinstall it? Ok , no problem...but is there any way to do this in user space , so the program could be shared with users and installed easily?

Comment: `Lowest level` != `userspace`. ... Packaged kernels aren´t that hard to install.

Comment: You can look into software that does this already on some level, like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_Common_Input_Method - when SCIM is enabled, all keyboard input is intercepted by it to provide things like Chinese character input on western layout keyboards. It uses iBus, I think.

Comment: @deviantfan lol...true...and thanks... I think from your comments , that my best option is to learn linux kernel module programming. Will do!

Comment: sounds like you're trying to make a transparent keylogger. Honestly, a kernel module is your best bet. but note, at the lowest level these are NOT ASCII codes being read in, they are scancodes.

Comment: Predicting keys for every operation ever? What about when you type passwords? Or type URLs by hand?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't modify keyboard drivers since this will require you to have a solution for every keyboard manufacturer.(and there are quite a lot of these..)

Instead you should patch a kernel function that is called by all drivers before passing the input further up the stack.

To start with, you could patch [input_event](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/input.c#L429) which is usually called by all input drivers [see documentation here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/device-drivers/API-input-event.html) (not only keyboard but also mouse and other devices)

In any case you will have to "decode" the input scan code where you might find [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/event-codes.txt) documentation useful.

For more information on kernel patching read [here](https://github.com/dynup/kpatch) and [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/applying-patches.txt).

Comment: would you have any idea on how this could be implemented as a kernel module? I know it's not hard to do with an IRQ on a PS/2 keyboard. Just the behavior of intercepting the keystrokes somewhere and possibly modifying them.